# Ignore empty lines [\t\s] spaces or tabs

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

### So I have this regex:

https://regex101.com/r/Puggjm/5

And I am basically, trying to ignore all the line numbers followed by space or nothing. My current regex: `^[\d\s].+(?:[A-Z\s]*)*$`

The line numbers followed by nothing are actually not ignored.

Comment: That is because the `.+` expects at least one character.

Comment: Could you indicate exactly what lines are expected to match from the example given?

Comment: So I should use OR or something else?

Comment: @jensgram, see this: https://regex101.com/r/Puggjm/4 - it's correct, but I want to expand so that it ignores the number lines that are not followed by any other new character set, string line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a negative lookahead to assert that what follows is not 1+ digits followed by 0+ times a whitespace character:

```
^(?!\d+\s*$)\d+.+$
```

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?!\d+\s*$)` Negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not 1+ digits followed by 0+ times a whitespace character and the end of the string
- `\d+.+` Match 1+ times a digit and 1+ times any character
- `$` End of the string

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n8mqVk/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/WJIMfl)

Example using [findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=findall#re.findall):

```
import re
regex = r"^(?!\d+\s*$)\d+.+$"
test_str = ("Here goes some text. {tag} A wonderful day. It's soon cristmas.\n"
    "2 Happy 2019, soon. {Some useful tag!} Something else goes here.\n"
    "3 Happy ending. Yeppe! See you.\n"
    "4\n"
    "5 Happy KKK!\n"
    "6 Happy B-Day!\n"
    "7\n"
    "8 Universe is cool!\n"
    "9\n"
    "10 {Tagish}.\n"
    "11\n"
    "12 {Slugish}. Here goes another line. {Slugish} since this is a new sentence.\n"
    "13\n"
    "14 endline.")
print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE));
```

When there is a dot after the digit, you could use:

[`^(?!\d+\.\s*$)\d+.+$`](https://regex101.com/r/971lsA/1/)

Comment: @JohnSmith You added a dot after the digit.

Comment: Yes, that's because that's the way the original content is. So how can I capture with the dot.

Comment: Like this you mean? `^(?!\d+\.\s*$)\d+.+$` https://regex101.com/r/971lsA/1/

Comment: Yes, indeed mate.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches only 1 digit, change it with [this simplified version](https://regex101.com/r/Puggjm/7):

```
^\d+\b.+$
```

Comment: 13 and 11 are still matched, despite that both lines are followed by NULL or empty string.